# How can I attach RAWs to already imported JPEGs in Aperture?

Tags: aperture, camera-raw

I shoot photos in RAW+JPEG mode since I got my DSLR. In the beginning I only used the JPEGs but lately I'm using RAW more and more. Unfortunately I imported only JPEGs in my first projects in Aperture. I already tagged, starred and cropped a lot of images and don't want to lose that information. However, I would now like to attach the RAWs to the old JPEGs, so I can do more editing on these images.

I didn't find any way to create a RAW+JPEG original in Aperture other than importing as such right in the beginning.

Is it possible to attach RAWs to JPEGs after the fact?